# Appium - strange message when initializing appium (ruby/BrowserStack)

Tags: appium

I am writing a series of appium mobile ui tests using ruby and executing the tests in BrowserStack.  Here are my desired capabilities and appium initialization:

```
caps = {
  "browserstack.user": ENV["BROWSERSTACK_USER"],
  "browserstack.key": ENV["BROWSERSTACK_ACCESS_KEY"],
  "browserstack.local": true,
  platformName: "ios",
  device: "iPhone 11",
  os_version: "14",
  app: myapp_ios,
  project: "Product Name",
  build: "Build ID #{build_id}",
  name: "Some Test Case"
}

Appium::Driver.new({
                     caps: caps,
                     appium_lib: {
                       server_url: "http://hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub"
                     }
                   }, global_driver: true)
```

When I initialize Appium, I get this message

```
Use myapp_ios directly since /Users/kroe761/Documents/Automation/Automation-Projects/myapp-tests-automation/myapp_ios does not exist.
```

This doesn't affect the test at all, but I write automation for manual app testers and I want to clean up the terminal output as much as possible so they only see what they need to see.  The `app` desired cap is the custom id I gave my app when I uploaded it to BrowserStack, so it obviously doesn't exist on my file system.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It should point to the ipa file that you are planning to automate.